# Are Euclidean distances a monotone function of inner products?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, trigonometry, metric-spaces, euclidean-geometry

Does the sum of all pairs of inner-products of k vectors (real) have to decrease if the sums of Euclidean distances between all pairs of $k$ vectors happens to decrease? Similarly-if decrease is replaced by increase, does it hold true? Is there an obvious Euclidean geometry based proof to it-because as the inner-products decrease the product of the norms and the cosine of the angle decreases? Can you clarify the reasoning more cogently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\{v_{i}\}_{i=1}^k$ be a set of $k$ vectors in $\mathbf{R}^n$. By "sum of all pairs of inner-products", presumably you mean something like
$$
\sum_{i<j} \langle v_{i}, v_{j}\rangle,
$$
and by "sum of Euclidean distances between all pairs" you mean
$$
\sum_{i<j} \|v_{i} - v_{j}\|.
$$

Consider what happens with *two* vectors. Since you're asking about monotonicity, we may as well square the distance, so the functions in question are
$$
\langle v_{1}, v_{2} \rangle = \|v_{1}\|\, \|v_{2}\| \cos\theta
\quad\text{and}\quad
\|v_{1} - v_{2}\|^{2} = \|v_{1}\|^{2} + \|v_{2}\|^{2} - 2\langle v_{1}, v_{2} \rangle.
$$
It's fairly clear there is no general monotonicity relation between these two functions: Holding the inner product constant you can increase or decrease the distance squared, and holding the distance constant you can increase of decrease the inner product. (By continuity, you can therefore increase or decrease either function while increasing the other.)

**Added in edit**: Let's assume each $v_{i}$ is a unit vector. Writing $\langle v_{i}, v_{j}\rangle = \cos\theta_{ij}$, the double angle formula for cosine gives
$$
\|v_{i} - v_{j}\|
  = \sqrt{\|v_{1}\|^{2} + \|v_{2}\|^{2} - 2\langle v_{1}, v_{2} \rangle}
  = \sqrt{2 - 2\cos\theta_{ij}}
  = 2\sqrt{\sin^{2}(\tfrac{1}{2}\theta_{ij})}
  = 2 |\sin(\tfrac{1}{2}\theta_{ij})|.
$$
For each pair $i < j$, the distance is therefore a decreasing function of the dot product.

For a set of three or more vectors, however, the angles $\theta_{ij}$ are constrained in complicated ways, and I don't see any way to make a corresponding deduction about
$$
\sum_{i<j} \langle v_{i}, v_{j}\rangle = \sum_{i<j} \cos\theta_{ij}
\quad\text{versus}\quad
\sum_{i<j} \|v_{i} - v_{j}\| = 2\sum_{i<j} |\sin(\tfrac{1}{2}\theta_{ij})|.
$$

To the contrary, taking $v_{1} = (1, 0)$, $v_{2} = (-1, 0)$, and $v_{3} = (\cos\theta, \sin\theta)$, the sum of the dot products is $-1$ for all $\theta$, but the sum of the distances is not constant, i.e., can be either increased or decreased by varying $\theta$. By the continuity argument mentioned earlier, you can therefore increase or decrease the sum of the distances while increasing the sum of the dot products.

To summarize: You have no monotonicity for arbitrary sets of two vectors; inverse monotonicity for a set of two vectors of fixed lengths; and no monotonicity for an arbitrary set of three unit vectors (even in the plane). You haven't said much about the constraints you're willing to impose, but I'm afraid the prospects for a non-trivial monotonicity relation do not look good.

Comment: If the Vectors are constrained to be of fixed norm/magnitude, would that lead to a monotonic relation, either direct or inverse? I am trying to find a constraint on the vectors, that would lead to a monotonic relation.